# Correct way to deal with index page - Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

**Correct way to deal with index page - Spring Boot**

Im insecure about the fact I have more than one method to serve the index page.

Is the code below correct or is there a better way to serve index, index.html and '/' with a single method?

Should I be dealing with this with the .htaccess file on apache? I dont want to keep mixing these two together.

```
@Controller
public class MainPage {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioProvider usuarioProvider;

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView listar() {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
        //

        try {
            Usuario u = usuarioProvider.customUserDetails();

            modelAndView.addObject("nomeUsuario", u.getNomeCompleto());
            modelAndView.addObject("ultimoAcesso", u.getUltimoAcessoFormatado());
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           ErrorLogger.log(ex);
        }

        //
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping("/index.html")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        return listar();
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        return listar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of cource, `@GetMapping` [value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#value--) can handle both `/`, `/index` and `/index.html` request paths at the same time.

```java
@Controller
public class MainPage {

    private final UsuarioProvider usuarioProvider;

    public MainPage(UsuarioProvider usuarioProvider) {
        this.usuarioProvider = usuarioProvider;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = {"/", "/index", "/index.html"})
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
        try {
            Usuario u = usuarioProvider.customUserDetails();
            modelAndView.addObject("nomeUsuario", u.getNomeCompleto());
            modelAndView.addObject("ultimoAcesso", u.getUltimoAcessoFormatado());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ErrorLogger.log(ex);
        }

        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```